# Android Developer How get versionCode or versionName from play market

Tags: android

I need to check version on play market.

I don't how can i do it.

I try find decision on google, but i no fond details for my problem.

My code is:

```
    PackageInfo manager;
      try {
        manager = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        Integer curVersion = manager.versionCode;
        Log.d("Cosmopizza", "Installed version = " + curVersion);
        Integer marketVersion = ??????;
        Log.d("Cosmopizza", "Market version = " + marketVersion);               
        String _url = getGooglePlayStoreUrl();    
        Log.d("Cosmopizza", "link to market = " + _url);    
        if (curVersion
```

Comment: First, it's not the correct and whole code. Second: What exactly is the problem? Do you want to get the Version of the Google Play Market which is installed?

Comment: I need get versioncode of my app from market, for send user notification for update, and block to use app next.

Answer (score 0):

there is no api inside android or google play services to get the latest version of you app.

you have two choices how to get the version

- build a small webservice where you manually enter the latest version and check against this service
- parse the play store website to get the latest version information (best in a custom webservice). but i think there you'll only get the versionName and not the versionCode.  it seems there is an [api service](http://www.playstoreapi.com/)(100 free requests/month) that helps with this trick otherwise you could try something like [this](https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API) or [this](https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/) but no idea if they still work. :)

good luck :)